# ']' expected while trying to access into a position of an array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, netbeans

I created an array of type "TablasDeSimbolos" with 2 positions and when I am trying to access into the first position it gave me an error. I am using NetBeans 8.0.2.

The exact message I got it is:

```
cannot find symbol

symbol: class tablaDeSimbolos

location: class Sintactico

']' expected
```

Here it is the code:

```
TablaDeSimbolos tablaDeSimbolosActual = null;
TablaDeSimbolos[] tablasDeSimbolos = new TablaDeSimbolos[2];
tablasDeSimbolos[0] = null; //The error it's here
```

And the class TablaDeSimbolos

```
public class TablaDeSimbolos {
    public TablaDeSimbolos() {
    }

    private List<String[]> tablaSimbolos = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    //Funcion que anade una entrada a la tabla de simbolos donde el lexema es el nombre de variableo funcion,
    //El tipo es el tipo (entero, cadena, boolean) si es funcion el valor es null, el desplazamiento es desde donde
    //empieza a escribir la variable(valor inicial 0) y el paso de parametro puede ser por VAL - VALOR o REF - REFERENCIA
    public void anadirATS(String lexema, String tipo, String desplazamiento, String pasoDeParametro) {
        String[] nuevaEntrada = {lexema, tipo, desplazamiento, pasoDeParametro};
        tablaSimbolos.add(nuevaEntrada);
    }

    public boolean buscarEnTS(String entrada) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tablaSimbolos.size(); i++) {
            if (entrada.equals(tablaSimbolos.get(i)[1])) //Aqui obtenemos el lexema de la entrada en la tabla
            {
                return true; //Si lo encontramos retornamos true
            }
        }
        return false;//Si no encontramos el lexema en la tabla entonces false
    }
}
```

Comment: the error says ```class tablaDeSimbolos``` with **lowercase t**. any chance that you have declared a variable of type ```tablaDeSimbolos``` instead of ```TablaDeSimbolos```?

Comment: I dont think so, I even tried with this code:

    int[]  numeros = new int[2];
    numeros[0] = 2;

I got the same error..

Comment: Give us the entire Sintactico class, and the entire error message.  Don't just give us the parts that you think are likely to cause the error.

Comment: I dont think is an error of the class Sintactico @arcy I already tried in a new class empty and the same error, even when I tried to declare and access to an array of int

Comment: The error says that you have used "tablaDeSimbolos" as a class name (but your class is called **T**ablaDeSimbolos. I suspect you haven't been posting the code that caused the error.

Comment: That's not an exception; it's a compile-time error.

Comment: So, you don't know what the problem is, but you're picking the parts of things that you think cause the error.  You have the wrong parts.  This isn't surprising, see sentence 1.  In order to be of help, we need the relevant information; since you do NOT know what is relevant, it is best if you give us the whole thing; it is especially best in this case, since the whole thing isn't that large.  But if you want to continue to be convinced that, although you cannot answer your own question, you know exactly what is and is not relevant to it, go ahead.

Comment: @arcy if you want next time Ill add the 400 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code nothing wrong with it.

However **Can't find Symbol** caused by following reasons,

1. You are not Importing class file.
2. Or Classpath of your this class is not available to location where you are accessing.

So you are using Neatbeans so 1st is not your prob. Then looks like 2nd is somehow causing problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I modify the classpath for getting it right? I even try declaring the array in a new class (empty) and got the same..

Answer (score 0):

```
tablasDeSimbolos[0] = null; //The error it's here
```

I doubt it. Message said about `tablaDeSimbolos`, not `tablasDeSimbolos`. It looks like you're disspelled your variable and compiler tries to identify this token as class name.

Comment: I rename the class TablasDeSimbolos to TS, same error.

Comment: Try to rename variable tablasDeSimbolos to tablaDeSimbolos

Answer (score 0):

I found the error,  I cannot access into an array in the class without a method.
The solution is create the array as an atribute of the class and then use a method for access into the position of the array and modify.

Thanks for help.